# Which of the following set is countable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $X$ be the set roots of unity in $\mathbb C$. Let $S(X)$ be the set of all sequences of elements in $X$. Which of the following subset of $S(X)$ is countable ?

1. The set $ \ \ A \ \  $ of all $(x_n) \in  S(X)$ such that $(x_n)$ is an eventually constant sequence .
2. The set $ \ \ B \ \ $ of all $(x_n) \in  S(X)$ such that $x_n = 1$, whenever n is prime number.
3. The set $ \ \ C \ \ $ of all $(x_n) \in  S(X)$ such that each $x_n$ is 26th root of unity .
4. The set $ \ \ D \ \ $ of all $(x_n) \in  S(X)$ such that $x_{2n} = 1$ for all n$\geq$ 1 .

I think answer is (3), because  number of 26th root of unity is finite. so $C$ is countable

Comment: Do you think there is only one countable answer? I would guess your job is to show for each set if it is countable or not.

Comment: Every real number in $[0,1)$ can be written in base $26$ in at least one way, possibly two. Since $26$ is a finite number, that means $[0,1)$ is countable. Right? Nope! Saying "because number of root is finite" is not justification. You need to be logical, not wishy-washy!

Answer (score 1):

Even if $x_n$ was limited to second roots of unity (or primitive third roots) there would be an uncountably infinite number of such sequences (think binary representations of numbers between $0$ and$1$).

The answer is 1. Group all the sequences by when they get constant, and note that in each category there are countably many sequences, since for the purpose of counting them they might as well be finite.

Of course, you still need to show that 2 and 4 are uncountable.

Comment: eventually constan sequence $(x_n)$ if there exist x and a positive integer N such that $x_n$ = x for all n $\geq N$ . define $S_1 = \{ (x_n) \ \ | \ \ x_n = x \ \ for \ \ all \ \ n, \ \   x \in \ \ X \}$, similarly define $S_m = \{ (x_n) \ \ | \ \  x_n \ \ = x  \ \ for \ \ all \ \  n \geq m \ \ and \ \ x  \in  X\}$, I think $A = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}S_n$ , you says that $A$ is countable if $S_n$ is countable for all n and $S_n$ is countable if $X$ is countable . Please tell me how to prove that $X$ is countable.

Comment: $X$ is countable by the following argument: There is $1$ first root of unity in $X$. Counting the second roots adds one more point to $X$. Third roots and fourth roots each contribute two new points to $X$, and so on, each new degree $n$ of roots adding at most $n-1$ new points to $X$. Therefore you cn go degree by degree, for each degree $n$ give all the new $n$th roots their index in the countnig of $X$, and every root will eventually be counted by some natural number.

Comment: @ Arthur: Thank you so much